# GRPC channel in Spring Boot application cause ClassNotFoundException for AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder

Tags: spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

When I configure a `ManagedChannelBuilder` for a GRPC client, the method `ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(...)` causes a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for the class `io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder`.

This is caused by the grpc-api libary in the class `ManagedChannelRegistry`, when it tries to load the class `io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider`.

**GRPC client:**

```java
public class GrpcClient {
    public void request() throws InterruptedException {
        ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder
                .forAddress("myGrpcServerAddress",
                        12345)
                .useTransportSecurity()
                .keepAliveTime(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .keepAliveTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()

        MyServiceGrpc.MyServiceBlockingStub stub 
          = MyServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);

        MyResponse myResponse = stub.hello(MyRequest.newBuilder()
            .setFirstName("test")
            .setLastName("test")
            .build());

        System.out.println("Response received from server:\n" + myResponse);

        channel.shutdown();
    }
}
```

**The following method is causing the exception:**

```java
ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("myGrpcServerAddress",12345)
```

**Method of the library which causing the exception:**

```java
    static List<Class<?>> getHardCodedClasses() {
        List<Class<?>> list = new ArrayList();
       ...
        try {
            list.add(Class.forName("io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider"));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException var3) {
            logger.log(Level.FINE, "Unable to find NettyChannelProvider", var3);
        }

       ...
```

**The following dependencies were used to run the grpc client:**

```
"io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.61.1"
"io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.61.1"
"com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.7.1"
"io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.61.1"
"io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.61.1"
```

I already tried different grpc versions with the same result. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Just compared your dependencies with mine and I don't have the "io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.61.1" Can you try with just the shaded netty dependency?

Comment: I removed the dependency io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.61.1 and get the same problem. 
I could avoid this problem by using NettyChannelBuilder instead of ManagedChannelBuilder.